# Bind images from isolated storage in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I have a list box which binds a list of objects . Each object has the field image file name . Each of these images present in the isolated storage .

I have tried to implement binding of these images into the list box , I am not getting the images . Please advise on how to do this .

I have looked into many forums and unable to solve this .

Best Regards,
Yash

Comment: You could try to load your images into BitmapImages or WritableBitmaps and then bind this to your Images source property.

Answer (score 0):

Store your image in isolated storage in stream rather than images and than read the stream.

It will work for you. Below is the sample code.

store images in isolated like this

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("IsoStoreFile.png", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
 {
 //Save the image file stream rather than BitmapImage to Isolated Storage.
 byte[] content = new byte[e.Result.Length];
 e.Result.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
 isoStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
 isoStream.Flush();
 }
```

Now you can open the saved file and display it in an image:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = isoStore.OpenFile("IsoStoreFile.png", FileMode.Open))
 {
 BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
 bmp.SetSource(isoStream);
 img.Source = bmp;
 }
 }
```